# How to close a jquery dialog box on opening an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a javascript code below:

```
var alertText = "Hey.";
       $("div").remove("#confirmationDialogBox");
       $(document.body).append("<div id='confirmationDialogBox'></div>");
       $("#confirmationDialogBox").html('');
       $("#confirmationDialogBox").dialog({
           resizable: false,
           height: 140,
           title: 'Alert !!',
           modal: true,
           draggable: false,
           zIndex: 99999,
           buttons: [{
               "class": 'btnModalDisplay',
               text: "Ok",
               click: function () {
                   //Calls another function that shows an alert
               }}]
       }).text(alertText);
```

My problem here is, when the dialog box appears and onclick of 'ok' of the dialog box i have to call another function that shows an alert.But for some reason when i click 'ok', the dialog box doesn't close and the alert shows up. Could someone help how can I close the dialog box and then the alert shows up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.dialog("close")`, like below:

```
var alertText = "Hey.";
$("div").remove("#confirmationDialogBox");
$(document.body).append("<div id='confirmationDialogBox'></div>");
$("#confirmationDialogBox").html('');
$("#confirmationDialogBox").dialog({
   resizable: false,
   height: 140,
   title: 'Alert !!',
   modal: true,
   draggable: false,
   zIndex: 99999,
   buttons: [{
     "class": 'btnModalDisplay',
     text: "Ok",
     click: function () {
       // Calls another function that shows an alert
       $( this ).dialog( "close" ); // add this line to close dialog
     }
   }]
}).text(alertText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the click event like this:

```
$("#confirmationDialogBox").dialog({
  ...
  buttons: [{
    "class": 'btnModalDisplay',
    text: "Ok",
    click: function(e) {
      //Calls another function that shows an alert
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#confirmationDialogBox').dialog('close');
    }
  }]
});
```

DEMO:

```js
var alertText = "Hey.";
$("div").remove("#confirmationDialogBox");
$(document.body).append("<div id='confirmationDialogBox'></div>");
$("#confirmationDialogBox").html('');
$("#confirmationDialogBox").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: 140,
  title: 'Alert !!',
  modal: true,
  draggable: false,
  zIndex: 99999,
  buttons: [{
    "class": 'btnModalDisplay',
    text: "Ok",
    click: function(e) {
      //Calls another function that shows an alert
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#confirmationDialogBox').dialog('close');
    }
  }]
}).text(alertText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Yes, I tried using --$("#confirmationDialogBox").dialog("close");
But it still is not working!!!!!

Comment: I think there is some other issue in your end. Can you create a small demo for this? Like just a button and open the dialog on click of it and then also add the other alert and see if you can reproduce the issue using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841).

Comment: I have also added a small demo. You can see on ok button click the dialog is closing fine.